# Test multiple browsers PHPUnit selenium stops

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit

I have an error with my multiple browsers test PHPUnit.
When i launch my test, the test stops when i hqve qn error... But i would want that my test go to the end.
How can i do that? please.
I try to make a "try-catch" but nothing... :s

my class :

```
class Alltest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase
{

public static $browsers = array(
array(
    'name'    => 'Firefox',
    'browser' => '*firefox',
    'port'    => 4444,
    'timeout' => 50000,
  ),
array(
    'name'    => 'IExplorer',
    'browser' => '*iexploreproxy',
    'port'    => 4444,
    'timeout' => 50000,
  ),
array(
    'name'    => 'Chrome',
    'browser' => '*googlechrome C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe',
    'port'    => 4444,
    'timeout' => 50000,
  )
);


 public function setUp(){
 $this->setBrowserUrl(URL);
}


public function testAll(){

$this->windowMaximize();

echo "test all...";
$test = new testRegistration();
$test->Registration($this, $report);
$tabTest["reg"] = "'".$nbTestok . "/" . $nbTest;
    login($this, $report);
$test = new CreatQuest();
$test->create_questions($this, $report);
$tabTest["crea"] = "'".$nbTestok . "/" . $nbTest;
$test = new testDesign();
$test->Design($this, $report);
$tabTest["design"] = "'".$nbTestok . "/" . $nbTest;
$test = new testLocalisation();
$test->Localisation($this, $report);
$tabTest["local"] = "'".$nbTestok . "/" . $nbTest;
$test = new testAnalyse();
$test->Analyse($this, $report);
$tabTest["analyse"] = "'".$nbTestok . "/" . $nbTest;
$test = new accountTest();
$test->testAccount($this, $report);
$tabTest["cfgcompte"] = "'".$nbTestok . "/" . $nbTest;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use the php `assertEqual` and be sure not to use `verify` anything. (I'm not into the php tests commands)